# Powerquery add column in the n'th position

Tags: excel, powerquery

i want to add a column on the 3th place (order). is there a way to do that ?

```
TotalSum = Table.AddColumn(#"Pivoted Column", "Total Cost", each List.Sum(Record.FieldValues(Record.SelectFields(_, List.Difference(Table.ColumnNames(#"Pivoted Column"), {"Bütçe Kodu", "Bütçe Kalemi", "Ay-Yıl"} ))))),
#"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(TotalSum,{"Bütçe Kodu", "Bütçe Kalemi", "Total Cost", {{{{ the other column names here }}}}}
```

or after adding i can reorder the columns but i have a dynamic column names so i need again dynamically move this new column on the 3th place.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not add a column in a specified position.  You can instead create the new column, then dynamically move it, like in this example, moving column **e** to position **3**

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
x=List.Difference(Table.ColumnNames(Source),{"e"}),
#"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(Source,List.Combine({List.Range(x,0,2),{"e"},List.Skip(x,2)}))
in #"Reordered Columns"
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for the fast response but it couldnt find the third column... Expression.Error: The column 'Ay-Yıl' of the table wasn't found.

Comment: i forgot to change the Source on the first code ✌️✌️✌️

Comment: is there a way to insert directly on the 3rd column ?

Comment: Not that I know of. New columns get added on the far right

Comment: if you dont know, noone can know.... powerquery shall be more developed then )))

Comment: there's a place to suggest ideas for powerbi https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/  not sure if that covers powerquery, but give it a try